# Apply list of functions to value using Scala Cats

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

in haskell I could do the following to a string

```
let f = sequence [id, reverse]
f "test"
```

I am at a bit of a loss how to approach this in a better method using Cats. I currently have something like

```
val f = List(fun1,fun2)
val data = "test"

f map {fun => fun(data)}
```

Is there an implementations of Sequence or SequenceU that can accomplish this using Cats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more or less exactly the same, except that the syntax is a little different, you need some extra imports, and the generic version isn't as convenient since Scala's `String` isn't just an alias for a list of characters:

```
import cats.instances.function._, cats.instances.list._, cats.syntax.traverse._

val funcs: List[String => String] = List(identity, _.reverse)

val f = funcs.sequenceU
```

In Haskell `sequence` requires a `Traversable` instance for the outer type constructor of its argument, and a `Monad` instance for the inner type constructor. Cats's `sequence` is almost the same—`Traversable` is called `Traverse` (because the name `Traversable` is already taken by the standard library), and it requires an `Applicative` instance instead of `Monad` (which is a more accurate constraint—Haskell's `sequence` only requires a monad instance for historical reasons).

If you wanted you could just import `cats.implicits._`, but that brings in a lot of other stuff. The imports above provide the minimal type class instances and syntactic extensions you need.

You can use `f`, which is a `String => List[String]`, like this:

```
scala> f("test")
res0: List[String] = List(test, tset)
```

Note that if you're on 2.12.1 and have the `-Ypartial-unification` compiler flag enabled, you can just write `.sequence`, not `.sequenceU`. Why you need the `U` on earlier Scala versions is a long story—see my [blog post here](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/07/11/roll-your-own-scala/) for an explanation.